How to navigate using the navigator key little bit complex?
I have created app where the user get notification when user tap on the notification it's goes to notification history page here simply I push the notification screen in stack when the other notification comes on the Notification screen then user tap on the screen then did not push the notification screen again in the stack and also the notification pop up is made out using Dialog so the tap event listen from the other file so to navigate to screen I use the global navigator Key to do navigation in the app. For the temporary usage I am completely replace that screen with notification screen but here is the problem is the it's delete the whole state so while navigate to the other screen the whole screen is reload again and there is so many data calling API stuff so I don't want that.Then how to resolve this navigation problem?
Here is the code of notification which is trigged form the fcm api file when ever foreground notification received.
dynamic newNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  final context = navigatorKey.currentState!.context;
  showDialog(
      context: navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
      builder: (ctx) => Dialog(
            elevation: 10,
            insetAnimationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            insetAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 4),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
                navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => NotificationHistory(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: // notification UI widget
            ),
          ));
}

as above showen that if the notification arrive in the app in any screen I tried to pushRplacement that page with NotificationHistory screen and in NotificationHistory  when the back button pressed It replace NotificationHistory with home screen but I don't want that. I want to check that if in notificatoin screen the notificatoin come then do not push that page if not then push NotificationHistory  page.

Please add the code too.

Sorry, now it's added.

you can make condition in notification screen if the condition satisfies you can change the route onPress of back button or else the back button will let you go to home page.
